# Detecting a keyword in URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to detect something like this:

```
http://xxx.imageshack.com/xx/xx.xx
```

*x* is an arbitrary number of letters long. Also, it could be `http://xxx.imageshack.com/xxx.xxx` or `http://xx.imageshack.com/xxx/xxx.xxx`. How do I do that in Javascript?

Eventually, I want to make sure that the site is imageshack and not `http://xxx.randomsite.com/xxx`, so the word between `*._.com` is critical.

I am trying this

```
if (!/^http:..[^\/]+imageshack.+\/.+$/i.test(this.src)){
    alert(this.src);
}
```

It does not work properly.
I just need the code that goes in the if statement or tips to fix it.Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after.

```
/^http:\/\/[a-z]{2,3}\.imageshack\.com\/([a-z]{3}\/)?[a-z]{3}\.[a-z]{3}$/i.test( this.src )
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. I put in the $ before $i.test(this.src) btw. I was getting all URLS including the ones that i wanted to ignore (the ones that were right) but with this i am getting none at all.

Comment: @illusionist, I forgot to escape the forward-slash in the subdirectory check, that's probably why it failed (but you should have seen a js error). I also added in your `$` to the end. I've tested this in [Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) based on your requirements and it passes both.

Comment: thanks kevin, what if there are numbers in the xxx too?Does [a,z]{2,3} mean it could be from a to z with length 2 or 3 ? What if i want to make length 0-0 with a combination of [a,z] and [0,9]

Comment: @Illusionist, are underscores also allowed?

Comment: @Illusionist, `[a,z]{2,3}` means any combination of letters a-z 2 or 3 times. If you want to add numbers only you would make it `[a-z0-9]{2,3}`. If you want/need to increase the number of matches, you'd change up the `{2,3}` to what you need. I'd suggest absorbing [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: thanks, any way of including special characters like "." in [a-z0-9] too? thanks !!

Comment: @Illusionist, `.` in that context is not special. Just add it in `[a-z0-9.]`. Only `-`, `\ `, `[`, and `]` are special.

Comment: thanks kevin, i have one more question . Imageshack uses a random number of "\" so I thought i could use the .* after imageshack.us but i want to block malformed urls like imageshack.us.x10.mx (just an example), so I want to use the .* until i hit another ".".. is that possible? I am using this right now                       http:\/\/[a-z0-9]{1,12}\.imageshack\.us.*

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your problem. I would open another question. I also don't see why you unaccepted this answer.